# IMEI code -66 explanation?

Tags: android, mobile

The IMEI code is a fifteen digit. But on my phone the IMEI code ends with "-66"(123456789123456-66). my question is : what's the "-66 " at the last of the IMEI code mean?

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity#Structure_of_the_IMEI_and_IMEISV_.28IMEI_Software_Version.29

Answer (score 0):

> The Structure of an IMEI Number IMEI numbers either come in a 17 digit
> or 15 digit sequences of numbers. The IMEI format currently utilized
> is AA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-D:
>
> AA: These two digits are for the Reporting Body Identifier, indicating
> the GSMA approved group that allocated the TAC (Type Allocation Code).
>
> BBBBBB: The remainder of the TAC (FAC)
>
> CCCCCC: Serial sequence of the
> Model (SNR)
>
> D: Luhn check digit of the entire model or 0 (This is an
> algorithm that validates the ID number) (CD)

Source: http://www.imei.info/faq-what-is-IMEI/